# Calling a C++ DLL in Python which returns an object reference

Tags: c++, python, dll, ctypes

After a long research i have decided to write a question.
I have a C++ DLL which has one exported function : ObjectType* getInstance()
With this instance, the function returns, i can get access to all the other public functions.

My problem now is, that i want to use this thing in Python. When i access getInstance with ctypes i only get an integer value instead of an instance.
The next thing i tried was to write an Python extension in C++. But this also didn't work out.

Any ideas.

Thank you very much for your help.

Best regards.

Comment: Have you looked into things like [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/python/doc) or [SWIG](http://swig.org)? They make interfacing Python with c++ very easy

Comment: C++ classes and DLLs don't mix very well in my view.  You usually end up constraining the DLL's client to use the same compiler as that which was used to build the DLL. I would export a flattened interface of `extern "C"` functions. Make these non-member functions whose first parameter is the object instance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't access a C++ type directly from Python.  You
have to wrap it with some (often a lot of) C or C++ code: it's not
difficult, but it does take time.  See [Extending and
Embedding the Python Interpreter](http://docs.python.org/extending/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the replies so far. I have already started to develop such an extension. Playing around there for a few days now.